# Efficient comparison of new data with records from a large database

Tags: mysql

I need to compare a set of URLs (50000 - 100000) with the records of database table with circa 20.000.000 rows. I have some legacy code that does this by loading all the data from the database to an hash and makes the comparisons after. While this works, it needs to be improved memory-wise (speed is not an issue for now).

An alternative that I am considering is to split the input data (by domain, for instance) and do several selects to the database. This may work for some inputs but it will not scale for everything.

Another alternative is to query the database for each input and not loading any data into memory. I am afraid that this may be too slow.

I am using mysql. Anyone as experience with a problem like this one? Migrating all the data to another system / dbms is an option.

---

Comment: 100k selects can be performed quick enough if indexes are set properly.

Comment: Should we presume that doing this via straight SQL querying doesn't work?

Comment: That is an option. I will try to do that first and see how it works. I was just wondering where there was a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: do you need to insert back into the large table after the comparison (not found) ?

Comment: Yes, I will need to do an insert if the record does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an index on the column and are doing a simple `a = b` comparison, than querying for each input shouldn't be a problem.

Queries like that shouldn't take more than a couple of milliseconds when using indexes so even with 50.000 urls that shouldn't take much more than 10 minutes.

Comment: Yep, and it can be speed up with comparing not by `=`, but by `url IN (10-50-100 urls)`.

Answer (score 0):

Define unique key on url column (assuming is already unique),
add a column row_count to the big table

```
 alter table big_table add column_row_count int(1) not null default 0;
 insert into big_table 
 select all_columns, 0 from small_table 
 on duplicate key set row_count=1;
```

those `row_count=1` is the duplicated records

Or you are not interest to get back what are the duplicated records,
simply do an

```
insert ignore ...
```